# Wrong UIToolbar Appears After Popping View

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uitoolbar

I'm new to Objective-C/Cocoa Touch and hope someone can help with the following issue.

I've got a view with a mapview control and a UIToolBar at the bottom of the screen. When a user clicks a pin on the map they can drill down to a grouped UITableView with details of the location.

This is done by pushing a new navigationController:

```
MapAnnotation *tappedLocation = (MapAnnotation *)[view annotation];

LocationDetailsViewController *placeDetails = [[LocationDetailsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LocationDetailsViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:placeDetails animated:YES];
[placeDetails release];
```

In the grouped UITableView there's also a UIToolbar at the bottom of the screen, but it's set up programmatically (code below).

The issue is that when the user leaves the grouped UITableView and comes back to the main view with the map, they still see the UIToolbar from the UITableView, not the original one that was set up in IB.

Anyone know how I can 'cancel' the UIToolbar from the grouped UITableView?

```
UIToolbar *toolbar = [UIToolbar new];
toolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleDefault;
[toolbar sizeToFit];
toolbar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 436, 320, 44);
toolbar.tag = 123;

UIBarButtonItem *flexItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]   
    initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace
    target:nil
    action:nil];

UIBarButtonItem *emailButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
    initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAction
    target:self
    action:@selector(email:)];

//Add buttons to the array
NSArray *items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: flexItem, flexItem, flexItem, emailButton, nil];
[emailButton release];
[flexItem release];

//add array of buttons to toolbar
[toolbar setItems:items animated:YES];

[self.navigationController.view addSubview:toolbar];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't add the toolbar as a subview of the navigationController. That view stays on screen as long as the app is running (you'll be stacking up a lot of them if you keep on going into the details view and back).

Simply set the toolbar's items using `[UIViewController setToolbarItems:animated:]`

Comment: Perfect. I used your suggestion along with    [self.navigationController setToolbarHidden: NO animated: YES]; to hide/show the toolbar and it worked perfectly